# Best way to measure the tail weight of a distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, distribution-tails

I am trying to [solve this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4309598/what-is-this-lognormal-like-distribution) and after blindly testing a dozen different distributions. I realised that I am more interested in the extreme values rather than mod/median/mean, therefore I wanted to check its tail weight and try to find a distribution fitting large values of $x$ rather than all values of $x$.

I checked the literature and it feels like although kurtosis is used a lot for tail weight, there is no consensus.

A few works (or tutorials), describe tail weight as skewness. One would expect the more skewed a distribution is, the more likely it is to find a value far from $\mu+\sigma$ (or $\mu+2\sigma$), which makes sense.

I also read that it might be measured as kurtosis. If it is more than 3, the chance of finding a value far from $\mu+\sigma$ (or $\mu+2\sigma$) is lower. Yet [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126346/why-kurtosis-of-a-normal-distribution-is-3-instead-of-0), more descriptive than any paper or tutorial I read, it is stated that kurtosis is more of a measure of shoulders than tails.

I guess I am quite confused at this point, so what I have written so far might not make sense.

So, is there an accepted (universal) measure of tail weight that somehow alluded my google search?  If not, what is the best way to measure the tail weight? Is there a list of tail weights for distributions depending on their parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm familiar with the terms [fat-tailed distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-tailed_distribution) and heavy-tailed distribution.  If your Question is really "is there an accepted (universal) measure of tail weight," then the answer is no.  For one thing a distribution with real support might have two tails or one tails, so skewness or kurtosis might be more appropriate for that reason.  Even the terminology is a bit fuzzy on whether fat-tail is synonymous with heavy-tail or is more specific.  Your interest/motivation would help Readers be more responsive.

Comment: @hardmath **No** is a perfectly valid answer as long as you back it up, like you did in this comment :)

Comment: @hardmath So, is there a generally accepted measure of tail weight for a unimodal distribution with a support set of non-negative real numbers with a single  tail?

Comment: You started by saying you "wanted to check its tail weight and try to find a distribution fitting large values of $x$..."  Note the [Lévy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution), a one parameter family with undefined skew and kurtosis, and the more general families of [inverse-gamma distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution).  Also see Cross Validated: [Is a fat tail same as skew](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/155338/37509) and Math.SE: [Fat Tail / Large Kurtosis Discrete Distributions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167656/3111)

Comment: @denis I already accepted an answer but if you convert this into an answer I'd upvote.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a universally accepted measure of "tail weights".  In particular higher moments starting with skew and kurtosis may not exist (or be unbounded/infinite if one prefers to think in those terms).

As a practical matter one is sometimes asked to recommend a statistical test that distinguishes a *sampled population* from proposed "thin-tailed" exponentially distributed models (or normal distributions in the two-tailed case), i.e. to test for the likelihood of a [fat-tailed distribution](https://www.statisticshowto.com/fat-tail-distribution/).  Such tests are notoriously unsatisfactory without an abundance of sampling data.  An introductory discussion is given by [John D. Cook's blog post](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/09/27/fat-tails-and-the-t-test/).  It is an active topic in the research literature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "best", but
"Expected future lifetime" $\equiv E( X - x \, | \, X \geq x )$ 
aka CME, conditional mean exceedance,
is an intuitive thing to look at: 
what's my remaining life expectancy if I'm $x$ years old ? 
Bryson,
"Heavy-tailed distributions: properties and tests" (1974,
pdf [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/technometrics/70-79/VOL-16-01/v1601061.pdf)
) says

> increasing CME provides a reasonable way of describing the heavy-tail phenomenon.

There's also Median future lifetime with median instead of mean.
It has, if I'm not mistaken, the nice property that 
Median future lifetime( quantile $q$ ) = quantile( ${1+q \over 2} ) - q$. 
A few quantiles of some heavy-tailed distributions,
normalized to q96 = 10:

```
-- quantiles [96 98 99 99.5] / q96  * 10
expon      :  [10 12 14 16]
pareto     :  [10 14 20 28]
halfcauchy :  [10 20 40 80]
```

See also
[Which has the heavier tail, lognormal or gamma?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86429/which-has-the-heavier-tail-lognormal-or-gamma)
ff. on stats.stack 
Wikipedia [Survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis)